# I looking for a way to read data from a text file and at the same time listen for the same data that's in another text file

Tags: python, string, text

```
import time
import sys, os
from pynput.mouse import Controller


speed = 200
fps = [time.sleep(1. / speed)]
mouse = Controller()
run = True
while run:
    "opens file"
    "two sets of data are being used in points"
    "mouse positions x and y"
    points = set()
    points1 = set()
    with open("mouse.txt", "r") as f:
        # each line separately
        for idx, line in enumerate(f):
            # strip \n  & strip ( and ) & split at ,
            pointstring = line.strip().strip("()").split(",")
            # guard against empty/non well formed lines
            if pointstring and len(pointstring) == 2:
                x, y = line.strip().strip("()").split(",")
                mouse.position = x, y  # = or (x, y)[0], (x, y)[1] same as -----> = x,y
                time.sleep(1. / speed)

            else:
                "if for some reason is doesn't work, it'll look for whats wrong in the txt file"
                print(f"Error in line {idx}: '{line}'")
```

---

text 1:

```
(568, 961)
(568, 958)
(568, 956)
(568, 955)
(568, 954)
(568, 953)
(568, 951)
(568, 948)
(568, 946)
(568, 944)
(568, 943)
(568, 937)
(568, 932)
(568, 931)
(568, 928)
(568, 927)
(568, 923)
(568, 921)
(568, 919)
(568, 915)
(568, 914)
(568, 911)
(568, 908)
(568, 907)
(568, 904)
(568, 899)
(568, 896)
(568, 893)
(568, 888)
(568, 885)
```

---

text 2:

```
(568, 911)
```

---

As soon as text 1 reaches the point at text 2, I want it to `print("yes")`.

Comment: Where are you reading "text 2"?

Comment: Also, just to save you some time, `import ast` / `ast.literal_eval` can take that string and return to you a 2-integer tuple.  Way easier than manually parsing it.

Comment: I actually tried to do it but could make it work so I wanted someone here to do it. But after what you mentioned above, it will most likely be easier for me to do it.

Comment: Before you do, read your second text file OUTSIDE the loop.  There's no reason to re-read it for every line in the first file.

Comment: would it work when there is more than 1 position in text 2?

Comment: What do you want it do in that case?  You can certainly read in a list of "stop points" and compare each new line to that list.

Comment: your right, It would work but I strip the data in text 2 and it wouldn't work.